# How to get rid of default value on a dependent select?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, combobox

I'm working on a pair of combos whose content is mutually related.

**HTML**

```
 <span>{{lblRegion}}</span>
  <select ng-model="currentRegion" 
          ng-options="region.name for region in regions" 
          ng-change="checkAll()">
  </select>


  <span>{{lblCountry}}</span>
  <select ng-model="currentCountry"
          ng-options="country.name for country in currentRegion.countries"
          ng-disabled="currentRegion.id===0">
  </select>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.regions = regions;
  $scope.currentRegion = regions[0];
  $scope.currentCountry = $scope.currentRegion.countries[0];

  $scope.checkAll = function() {

    if (currentRegion.id !== 0) {
      $scope.test = true;
    } else {
      $scope.test = false;
    }
  }

 var regions = [{
    'id': 0,
    'name': 'All',
    'countries': [{
      'id': '0',
      'name': 'All'

    }]
  },
  ...
```

The behavior has to fulfill this:

1. Both combos have an 'All' option.
2. The content of the 'region' combo sets the possible values of the 'country' combo.
3. If the region combo is set to 'All', the country combo gets disabled and its content is the option 'All'.

I want to get rid of the empty default option that always appears on the country combo. I've read that `ng-init` could do the work but [ng-init docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit) states that this issue should not be managed in this way.

How could I remove the empty option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default *blank* value was getting selected since the second `ng-option` depends on `currentCountry.countries`, which changes, and the value of `currentRegion`, which is `regions[0].countries[0]`, was not present in this list. This can be corrected by setting the value of the `currentRegion` to be the `currentRegion.countries[0]` as soon as `currentRegion` changes.

This can be done in the `ng-change`, as you have tried.

However, I do not trust ordering of `ng-change` and `ng-model`. Hence, I would prefer setting up a watch for the task: http://plnkr.co/edit/TnHC039Hg7x0Oj9DmEkk?p=preview

**Controller**

```
$scope.$watch('currentRegion', function (newVal) {
  if (typeof newVal !== 'undefined') {
    $scope.currentCountry = newVal.countries[0];
  }
})
```

**Template**

```
  <!-- Without ng-change -->
  <select ng-model="currentRegion" ng-options="region.name for region in regions"></select>
```

Comment: I like your answer... but I was wondering if there is a chance to evade the use of $watch...

Comment: @JPCF You can always use `ng-change="currentCountry = currentRegion.countries[0]"` though it would hide a bit of the logic in the template.

Comment: yeah... that was the other option... I wanted it to be entirely declarative... but, 'It doesn't matter the color of the cat if it hunts mice'

Comment: based on our discussion with @Maxim Shoustin could you remove the ng-init advise so I can accept your answer? I tried using it but it only took care of the value when doing the control's initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Write deep `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.currentRegion;
},
function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.currentCountry = newValue.countries[0].name;
}, true);
```

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lUvQBvizH1y6rGzgQ3f6?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: There is a strange behavior with your code. Suppose the following sequence: 1. Select a region, 2. select a country, 3. select 'All' in the region combo. The result for this operations is to set the country combo as blocked with the value ''. I'm working on that...

Comment: ng-init="currentCountry=currentRegion.countries[0].name" sets the value of the model to the value expected for the name of the country at index 0? e.gr. Querying for the id of currentCountry will return the value of the id for currentRegion.countries[0] after setting ng-init as you said?

Comment: Sorry mate, i changed my answer, I think there is no way but use `watch`. because `ng-init` initiated only once. added Plunker

Comment: yeah... also I was pondering on telling you about the documentation for ng-init. It is not recommended to use it... I'll use ng-change...

Comment: And like @musically_ut says, you don't need ng-change sice watch will take care about your model. see now Plunker without `checkAll` method

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to get rid of the blank is just to add the following to your checkAll() function:

```
$scope.currentCountry = $scope.currentRegion.countries[0];
```

like this:

```
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
    $scope.currentCountry = $scope.currentRegion.countries[0];
    if (currentRegion.id !== 0) {
      $scope.test = true;
    } else {
      $scope.test = false;
    }
  }
```

If you don't set a value for a select box, it adds a blank first item automatically. So to avoid this, is to obviously give it a value.